# Socket Programming Implementation Using Threading in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, java-threads

Here I can solve socket programming for chat application between multiple client and server where client can send multiple message to the server. But now I want to solve a new problem where conversion of any string from any client [each client can send at most 2 messages] into a FULL UPPERCASE string with the help of the server. The server will be able to serve at most 5 clients.

This is my client coe.....

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Client started..");
        Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 22222);
        System.out.println("Client Connected..");

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        while (true) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            String message = sc.nextLine();

            if(message.equals("exit")){
                break;
            }

            //sent to server...
            oos.writeObject(message);

            try {
                //receive from server..
                Object fromServer = ois.readObject();
                System.out.println("From Server: " + (String) fromServer);

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        socket.close();

    }
}
```

This is my server code........

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(22222);
        System.out.println("Server Started..");

        while (true) {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Client connected..");

            // new Server Thread Start.....
            new ServerThread(socket);


        }
    }
}

class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    Socket clientSocket;
    Thread t;

    ServerThread(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

            while (true) {
                //read from client...
                Object cMsg = ois.readObject();
                if (cMsg == null)
                    break;
                System.out.println("From Client: " + (String) cMsg);

                String serverMsg = (String) cMsg;
                serverMsg = serverMsg.toUpperCase();

                //send to client..
                oos.writeObject(serverMsg);
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "into a FULL UPPERCASE string"? Do you want to merge messages into one string? "aaa" from client1, "bbb" from client2 and FULL UPPERCASE means AAABBB?

Comment: That's not necessary. But I need mainly upto 2 message can sent from one client/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**// Sever side**

```
package sockettreading;
 
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
 
/**
 *
 * @author Amanur Rahman
 */
public class SocketTreading {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5050);
        System.out.println("Server is starting...");
        int cn=1;
        while (cn<=5) {
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("Client"+cn+" is connected \n" + s);
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("Assinging new thread for this client");
            Thread t = new ClientHandler(s, dis, dos);
            t.start();
            cn++;
        }
        System.out.println("Client limit cross");
        
        ss.close();
 
    }
}
 
class ClientHandler extends Thread {
 
    final Socket soc;
    final DataInputStream input;
    final DataOutputStream output;
    int i = 1;
 
    public ClientHandler(Socket s, DataInputStream dis,
            DataOutputStream dos) {
        this.soc = s;
        this.input = dis;
        this.output = dos;
    }
 
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String received;
        String ends;
        String toreturn;
        while (i <= 2) {
            try {
                output.writeUTF("Please write your message : ");
                String str = input.readUTF();
                System.out.println("Client msg is: "+ str.toUpperCase());
                output.writeUTF("Do you want to exit or continue ( if exit type \"ENDS\" ) ");
                ends = input.readUTF();
                if (ends.equals("ENDS")) {
                    System.out.println("Client" + this.soc + "send exit.");
                    this.soc.close();
                    System.out.println("Connection closed");
                    break;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            System.out.println("" + i);
            i++;
        }
 
        try {
            this.input.close();
            this.output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**// client side**

```
package sockettreading;
 
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
 
/**
 *
 * @author Amanur Rahman
 */
public class ClientThreading {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try(Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 5050);){
             System.out.println("Connected");
             Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        int i = 1;
        while (i <= 2) {
            System.out.println(dis.readUTF());
            String num1 = scn.nextLine();
            dos.writeUTF(num1);
 
            System.out.println(dis.readUTF());
            String num2 = scn.nextLine();
            dos.writeUTF(num2);
            System.out.println(dis.readUTF());
            String ends = scn.nextLine();
            dos.writeUTF(ends);
            if (ends.equals("ENDS")) {
                System.out.println("Closing the connection" + s);
                s.close();
                System.out.println("Connection closed");
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(dis.readUTF());
        s.close();
        dos.close();
        dis.close();
        }
        
        catch (IOException ex) {
            if(ex.getMessage()!=null){
                System.out.println("Already 5 clients are served so the server is closed: ");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Client 2 message already send. That's way the connection closed.");
            }
            
        }
 
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Please improve your answer by adding explanation for the code that you've posted. Understand that this isn't a help site per se, but rather a question and answer site where the goal is to provide questions and answers that help *future visitors* with similar problems, and in this situation, the quality of an answer's text is most important, and the answer code should demonstrate what was explained in the text. Please review the [answer] link for site best-practices when answering.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).